# PMI - Purhasing Managers Index

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, data-request, time-series

I need the PMI time series for an econometic project but it seems I can't get it for free on the internet.

Does anyone know where can I download it for free?
Also a proxy for this series would be great.
The sample size: monthly, from 1960-70 to 2016

Answer (score 1):

Such data can be found on Quandl, for example:

https://www.quandl.com/data/ISM/MAN_PMI-PMI-Composite-Index